# WAR version of WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2

I have recently downloaded the WSO2 API manager. I think it builds several war files when we start the WSO2 API manager using wso2server.bat. Is there any direct WAR version of the software available which I can deploy it any application server of my choice (e.g. weblogic, was)

Answer (score 0):

The API manager is much more than just several WAR files. The WAR files form only the frontend. So - you will have to use it as a product (and you cannot deploy it to other containers).